# Why does (presumably) every site's FAQ have screenshots from the Great Outdoors beta site?

Tags: feature-request, site-faq

Every non-beta site's FAQ is styled to match the permanent look and feel of the site for which it was made.  Why don't they have specialized screenshots as well?

Comment: We like to go camping. :) Ah, the great outdoors. *relaxes*

Comment: Is it a plot to drive traffic to outdoors.SE?  :)

Comment: Sorry what's the feature request?

Comment: The truckloads of cash would stop showing up at their door if it was found out they were paying someone to spend all their time taking screenshots of their sites, for their sites, instead of doing something actually productive.

Comment: Perhaps because there's better things to do than localize functionally identical screenshots?

Comment: It's a great outdoor conspiracy

Comment: The reason is caching. Imagine someone reading 20 FAQs per day … oh, wait …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it would be a waste of time.

Oh, there'd be some small benefit from it, no doubt. Always helps to see a screenshot that looks *exactly* like what you see on your own screen.

But it would also mean that every change to the design, on any of the sites, whether a massive re-work or a small bug-fix, would require remaking those screenshots.

Either design changes would be held up, or they'd be perpetually out of date anyway.

*Much* better to just use images taken from the default theme, which are already designed to be as clean and universally appealing as possible.

Comment: I think it would cause less confusion if you created a generic screenshot with a placeholder site name. ie. - 'Sitename' instead of 'The Great Outdoors.  You already do it for the 'What is reputation' screenshot by using 'John Doe'.  The other option is to use StackOverflow instead of Great Outdoors because some people may not even know The Great Outdoors site exists while many more will be familiar with SO.